# Drupal 7 OG Group Unsubscribe after given time period for member

Tags: 7, organic-groups, users, notifications

I am new to drupal 7 and was willing to implement something like time based unsubscription from a OG Group.

I have users added in OG Group. I want to implement time based unsubscription of the users already added in the group say 'Computers'.

User say 'Tony' is added to the group 'Computers' today, now I wish that a user 'Tony' should be unsubscribed from the group 'Computers' after a subscription of 3 months (a specific time period).

A Notification message should be sent to user 'Tony'.

All the process should be based on systems current date and the joining date of user 'Tony' to the group 'Computers'.

Please help me with any solution.

Answer (score 1):

This is definitely a job for [rules](http://drupal.org/project/rules). It is also quite a complexed subject as you are going to need to utilise components so that you can schedule this to happen every day. I would do it like this:

1. [Set up a views_bulk_operations view](http://dev.nodeone.se/en/using-vbo-to-load-list-of-objects-into-rules) that looks up all users that have been members of groups for 90 days.
2. [Create a rule component](http://drupal.org/node/1582182) that loads the list of users, loops through the list, sends a notification and unsubscribes the user from the group.
3. [Schedule the rule](http://drupal.org/node/1300068) to do this every day.

Comment: i am not able to create a view which shows username along with the membership creation date, so could you help me with it?

Comment: I have created a VBO but not able to load VBO in the rule section?